# How do I make save as a copy code in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba, save-as, excel-2019

I have an excel file. I want to make a code in VBA and this code saves sheet3 in a specific directory as a copy. File former is normal *(.xlsx)*. Also, this code saves sheet3 as pdf in a specific directory.
I make this code, but when run this code it opens my recent save file and closes my main file. I tried to fix this problem. But I can not fix it. So need help.

```
Sub Saveasdailog()
On Error Resume Next

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    .Title = "Location file and file Name Enter"
    .ButtonName = "Save Invoice"
    .InitialFileName = "E:\Execl Documents\Business management file\Edit invoice\" & Range("F9").Value
    If .Show = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file did not save.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Execute
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

There was only save as code.

I want my code to do two things at once. One is save as and save pdf.

Comment: The code you posted is only showing a dialog box. That's it. Next steps is to pick up the selected path and actually save it.

Comment: How can I make complete code in VBA to solve my task?